# form.Show() not working instead of form.ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm calling a form to show in a DataGridView some data I got as a result of processing inside a class. The code is the following:

```
class aldeloUpdater
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var guiForm = new GuiForm(); //  Instantiating the Form-derived class.
            Processing...
            foreach (...)
            {
                if ((bool)DBresponse["status"])
                {
                    guiForm.dataGridViewProducts = (List<Hashtable>)DBresponse["deliveriesSaved"]; // Passing the data to the DataGridView.
                    guiForm.ShowDialog(); // Showing the form.
                }
                else
                {
                    Processing...
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                Processing...
        }
    }
    More methods...
}
```

As you can see, the form is shown inside a loop that should be kept on running but as the form is shown as a modal, it stops the execution of the process. The result is

[image: guiForm.ShowDialog()]

Now to avoid to stop the execution of the program I changed `guiForm.ShowDialog();` for `guiForm.Show();`, but the result is this:

[image: guiForm.Show()]

What am I missing here? How can I get the same result as in the first graphic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your main thread exiting, thus clearing the UI, since `Show` doesn't block the UI thread

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say. But based on what you posted so far, most likely you've failed to provide the necessary `Application.Run()` call required to pump window messages to allow your window to work. Generally, the right way to do this is use the normal Winforms template (`Main()` calls `Application.Run()`) and then you have the non-UI stuff running as a background task that interacts with the UI as needed.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bwinforms%5D+run+processing+in+background+thread for inspiration. (Noting, however, that not all those search results apply, and some involve less-than-ideal programming practices.) If after reviewing the available information you are still having trouble, post a new question with a good MCVE and an explanation of your _specific_ problem.

Comment: You are violating every rule in the book, that is **not** what the Main() method of a GUI program should look like.  At least one side-effect is visible from the horizontal scrollbar, it looks like it came from the previous century because you didn't do this right.  The window looks like that because you don't have an Application.Run() call.  You'll encounter many more problems if you keep on this path, you'll have to throw it away.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your comment. I'm a one-month newbie to C#, this is my very first program and have never made stuff like this, I'm learning. Anyway, this Main() used to be a console app method that makes requests to a web server, process the data and finally calls a winform (which is "a plus"). I'll look into that "Application.Run()" thing and throw a new post if necessary. Meanwhile for you to get a better picture please read[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986799/best-way-to-pass-data-to-a-datagridview-form-from-another-non-form-class?noredirect=1#comment65363479_38986799)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'll appreciate you read my previous comment (they didn't let me to notify you as well).

Comment: Okay, I read it. Now what do you want me to do with it? As I already wrote in my previous comments, your program is currently upside-down. When you move from a console program to a GUI program, you need to adjust your thinking. The two work in very different ways. You need to let a GUI program be a GUI program; Visual Studio will do it correctly, if you let it. Then you can re-introduce your old console code as a background task that can work _within_ the GUI program, instead of trying to just bolt a GUI program onto the side of your original console program.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I tried to follow your suggestion but still don't get there, I'd really appreciate you take a look to this new post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108349/datagridview-form-shows-up-empty-after-background-worker-finish)